# How can I remove numbers from headings?

Tags: confluence

Accidentally clicked that little numbering menu next to the paragraph type menu and now all my headings have numbers on them:

```
1. Basics
...
  1.1 Overview
```

and so forth. How can I make those go away again? All the googling I've done turned up results like how to remove the numbering plugin or how to disable formatting entirely. I just want to remove the numbers from this one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click it again.  That'll turn it off.  The "little numbering menu" evidently works like a toggle switch.

Comment: Awww, fer crying out loud. I kept trying to fix it in the drop-down. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Same thing happened to me, it's an amazingly bad interface, even word gives you the option of selecting 'no numbering'.  Anyway, I made it go away by selecting 'custom' (as opposed to the default which was decimal).  I did not even have to add anything into the text boxes under custom.  I had no idea if this would work or not but it did but I am not going to try this again.  I only did this once.